# How to add dynamic filter drop down using Jqgrid?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have the following working code that searches the table using the jqgrid tool bar.

I want to add a dynamic drop down for the "Symbol" column, so that the drop will reflect the dynamic value of that column.
Also, I want to disable the search for  TotalValue and MaxLoan.

My [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/dev2020/615qovew/7/)

Code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var jsonData = {
      "Name": "Julie Brown",
      "Account": "C0010",
      "LoanApproved": "12/5/2015",
      "LastActivity": "4/1/2016",
      "PledgedPortfolio": "4012214.00875",
      "MaxApprovedLoanAmt": "2050877.824375",
      "LoanBalance": "1849000",
      "AvailableCredit": "201877.824375",
      "Aging": "3",
      "Brokerage": "My Broker",
      "Contact": "Robert L. Johnson",
      "ContactPhone": "(212) 902-3614",
      "RiskCategory": "Yellow",
      "rows": [{
        "ClientID": "C0010",
        "Symbol": "WEC",
        "Description": "Western Electric Co",
        "ShareQuantity": "20638",
        "SharePrice": "21.12",
        "TotalValue": "435874.56",
        "LTVCategory": "Equities",
        "LTVRatio": "50%",
        "MaxLoanAmt": "217937.28"
      }, {
        "ClientID": "C0010",
        "Symbol": "BBB",
        "Description": "Bins Breakers and Boxes",
        "ShareQuantity": "9623",
        "SharePrice": "74.29125",
        "TotalValue": "714904.69875",
        "LTVCategory": "Equities",
        "LTVRatio": "50%",
        "MaxLoanAmt": "357452.349375"
      }, {
        "ClientID": "C0010",
        "Symbol": "GPSC",
        "Description": "Great Plains Small Cap Stock",
        "ShareQuantity": "49612",
        "SharePrice": "14.24",
        "TotalValue": "706474.88",
        "LTVCategory": "Mutual Funds - Small Cap",
        "LTVRatio": "40%",
        "MaxLoanAmt": "282589.952"
      }]
    },
    mmddyyyy = "";
  /*********************************************************************/


  $("#output").jqGrid({
    url: "/echo/json/",
    mtype: "POST",
    datatype: "json",
    postData: {
          json: JSON.stringify(jsonData)
    },
    colModel: [
      /**    { name: 'ClientID', label:'ClientID',width: 80, key: true },****/
      {
        name: 'Symbol',
        width: 65
      }, {
        name: 'Description',
        width: 165
      }, {
        name: 'ShareQuantity',
        align: 'right',
        width: 85,
        classes: "hidden-xs", labelClasses: "hidden-xs",
        formatter: 'currency',
        formatoptions: {
          prefix: " ",
          suffix: " "
        }
      }, {
        name: 'SharePrice',
        label: 'Share Price',
        align: 'right',
        width: 100,
        classes: "hidden-xs", labelClasses: "hidden-xs",
        template: "number",
        formatoptions: {
          prefix: " $",
          decimalPlaces: 4
        }
      },
      /*{ label: 'Value1', 
                  name: 'Value1', 
                  width: 80, 
                  sorttype: 'number', 
                  formatter: 'number',
                  align: 'right'
              }, */
      {
        name: 'TotalValue',
        label: 'Total Value',
        width: 160,
        sorttype: 'number',
        align: "right",
        formatter: 'currency',
        formatoptions: {
          prefix: " $",
          suffix: " "
        }
      }, {
        name: 'LTVRatio',
        label: 'LTV Ratio',
        width: 70,
        sorttype: 'number',
        align: "right",
        formatter: 'percentage',
        formatoptions: {
          prefix: " ",
          suffix: " "
        }
      }, {
        name: 'LTVCategory',
        label: 'LTV Category',
        classes: "hidden-xs", labelClasses: "hidden-xs",
        width: 120,
        width: 165
      },

      {
        name: 'MaxLoanAmt',
        label: 'MaxLoanAmount',
        width: 165,
        sorttype: 'number',
        align: "right",
        formatter: 'currency',
        formatoptions: {
          prefix: " $",
          suffix: " "
        }
      }

    ],
    additionalProperties: ["Num1"],
    /*beforeProcessing: function (data) {
        var item, i, n = data.length;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            item = data[i];
            item.Quantity = parseFloat($.trim(item.Quantity).replace(",", ""));
            item.LTVRatio = parseFloat($.trim(item.LTVRatio *10000).replace(",", ""));
            item.Value = parseFloat($.trim(item.Value).replace(",", ""));
            item.Num1 = parseInt($.trim(item.Num1).replace(",", ""), 10);
            item.Num2 = parseInt($.trim(item.Num2).replace(",", ""), 10);
        }
    }, */
    iconSet: "fontAwesome",
    loadonce: true,
    rownumbers: true,
    cmTemplate: {
      autoResizable: true,
      editable: true
    },
    autoResizing: {
      compact: true
    },
    autowidth: true,
    height: 'auto',
    forceClientSorting: true,
    sortname: "Symbol",
    footerrow: true,
    caption: "<b>Collateral Value</b> <span class='pull-right' style='margin-right:20px;'>Valuation as of: " + mmddyyyy + "</span>",


    loadComplete: function() {
      var $self = $(this),
        sum = $self.jqGrid("getCol", "Price", false, "sum"),
        sum1 = $self.jqGrid("getCol", "MaxLoanAmt", false, "sum");
      //ltvratio =  $self.jqGrid("getCol","LTVRatio:addas", "Aved Loan Amount");
      $self.jqGrid("footerData", "set", {
        LTVCategory: "Max Approved Loan Amount:",
        Price: sum,
        MaxLoanAmt: sum1
      });
    }
  });

  $("#output").jqGrid('filterToolbar', {stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false, defaultSearch : "cn"});


    $(window).on("resize", function () {
        var newWidth = $("#output").closest(".ui-jqgrid").parent().width();
        $("#output").jqGrid("setGridWidth", newWidth, true);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent sorting in some columns (`TotalValue` and `MaxLoan`) you need just add `search: false` property in the corresponding column definitions.

To create dropdown in the searching toolbar for the `Symbol` column you can set the `searchoptions.value` with respect of `setColProp`. You can fill `value` based on the values returned from the server inside of `beforeProcessing`:

```
beforeProcessing: function (data) {
    var symbolsMap = {}, symbolsValues = ":All", rows = data.rows, i, symbol;
    for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        symbol = rows[i].Symbol;
        if (!symbolsMap.hasOwnProperty(symbol)) {
            symbolsMap[symbol] = 1;
            symbolsValues += ";" + symbol + ":" + symbol;
        }
    }
    $(this).jqGrid("setColProp", 'Symbol', {
        stype: "select",
        searchoptions: {
            value: symbolsValues
        }
    }).jqGrid('destroyFilterToolbar')
    .jqGrid('filterToolbar', {
        stringResult: true,
        searchOnEnter: false,
        defaultSearch : "cn"
    });
}
```

See the modified demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/615qovew/8/

Comment: @Oleg- Thank you this was really helpful

Comment: @user244394: You are welcome! If you find some answer or the question helpful you should vote it up. Is the problem is solved now? If the problem is solved then you should accept it additionally.