# Jqgrid dynamic filter with url data source

Tags: filter, drop-down-menu, jqgrid

I have a Jqgrid as follows:

```
 jQuery("#jQGridDemo").jqGrid({
            url: 'http://localhost:58404/JQGridHandler.ashx',
            colNames: ['Property ID', 'Property Ref', 'Short Address', 'Scheme Code', 'Scheme Name', 'Property Type', 'Tenure Type', 'Status', 'Management Cost','Rent Charge Month','SC Charge Month'],
            colModel: [
                        { name: 'PropertyID', index: 'PropertyID', width: 70, align: "left", stype: 'text', sortable: true},
                        {name: 'PropertyType',width: 80},
                        { name: 'TenureType', index: 'TenureType', width: 80, align: "center",  sortable: true },
                        { name: 'Status', index: 'Status', width: 75,  align: "center", sortable: true },
            ],
```

The grid works and is populated with the Json returned from the URL.
However, I am trying to implement a dynamically populated drop-down-filter on the PropertyType column and have been looking at Oleg's answer here: [How to add dynamic filter drop down using Jqgrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37954574/how-to-add-dynamic-filter-drop-down-using-jqgrid)

I have therefore added a "beforeProcessing" function:

```
 beforeProcessing: function (data) {
                var propertyMap = {}, propertyValues = ":All", rows = data.rows, i, symbol;
                for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                    symbol = rows[i].Symbol;
                    if (!propertyMap.hasOwnProperty(symbol)) {
                        propertyMap[symbol] = 1;
                        propertyValues += ";" + symbol + ":" + symbol;
                    }
                }
                $(this).jqGrid("setColProp", 'PropertyType', {
                    stype: "select",
                    searchoptions: {
                        value: propertyValues
                    }
                }).jqGrid('destroyFilterToolbar')
                    .jqGrid('filterToolbar', {
                        stringResult: true,
                        searchOnEnter: false,
                        defaultSearch: "cn"
                    });
            },
```

My question is, how do I pass the data returned from the URL to the "beforeProcessing: function (data)" -

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It is already passed. Not Sure that I understand. To this event is passed the data from the server before it is inserted into the grid. Also there are some differences in different jqGrid versions regarding this event - actually which version of jqGrid is used - Guriddo jqGrid, free-jqGrid or jqGrid <= 4.7?

Comment: I am using version 4.5.1. The debugger is telling me that rows is null. So I assume the data is not being passed to the function before it is inserted into the grid.

Comment: What is your datatype? If the datatype is local it will not be passed in version 4.5.  For this version the data is passed only if the datatype is json or xml. The problem does not exist in Guriddo jqGrid versions.

Comment: My datatype is Json.

Comment: try to console.log the data. It is possible that data.rows property does not exist according to the jsonReader . just before the rows = data.rows. make a console.log of data only

Comment: Thank-you for your responses. I am making progress. I have managed to debug the function in Visual Studio and can see that data is indeed populated. However, .rows is not available for my "dataset". – Do you know what method I could call to set the count of rows in order to use the property in the for loop?

Comment: You can debug the data in the browser - please search how to debug in browser. Can you please post here a simple response from the server?

Comment: This is the first "line" from the returned Json: [{"PropertyID":1,"PropertyRef":"1","ShortAddress":"99 ROCK LANE,BODMIN,PL91 1NR","SchemeCode":"700000","SchemeName":"LODMIN","PropertyType":"HOU","TenureType":"ASSURED","Status":"OCCUPIED","ManagementCost":"MGMT_15_PCENT_SW","RentChargeMonth":"APRIL","SCChargeMonth":"APRIL"}

Answer (score 0):

In case your data does not have a rows property you can modifiy your initial code like this:

```
 beforeProcessing: function (data) {
                var propertyMap = {}, propertyValues = ":All", rows = data, i, symbol;
                for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                    symbol = rows[i].Symbol;
                    if (!propertyMap.hasOwnProperty(symbol)) {
                        propertyMap[symbol] = 1;
                        propertyValues += ";" + symbol + ":" + symbol;
                    }
                }
....
```

The only that differ from your original code is replacing

rows = data.rows

with

rows = data,

Comment: Thanks. That one change has made all the difference. I am new to the Jqgrid. Which version would you recommend I use?

Comment: It depends what you expect. You can use our commercial version [Guriddo jqGrid](http://www.guriddo.net)  with guaranteed  support and development or you can use the open source fork [free-jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/) which has only support from Oleg without future Development